# Constant challenge with file permissions

Tags: php

I'm having problems with file permissions, that is my script is unable to create files and directories in the folder it resides within.

What should I do in order to make it possible for the script?

Comment: The first thing you should do is to add some more detail to the question. As it is now, it reads like "My car doesn't start. Why?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, you'd examine the script and determine exactly what it does, where it requires access, which type of access, and then determine the correct permissions for access. You certainly shouldn't apply a recursive permissions command from your cli, which is what you might find which a quick google search. This would be something like `chmod 777 -R directoryname`. That's a bad idea as it become a security risk pretty rapidly. You should apply the correct permissions to everything that script can touch.

To start with, here are resources to help learn a bit more about permissions. http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html or http://catcode.com/teachmod/

If you're unsure about the script, feel free to post code and inquire about what it's doing.

edit: If the script you're having trouble with has a community behind it, it would be best to inquire on the community message boards if they exist.