# Running a python file from php does not generate the output file

Tags: php, python, exec, os.system

I have a problem running another file from php. I want my php params to be the output of running a python file that calls another file itself.

Here is my php file:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $params = solve();
}

function solve() {
  exec("python array.py", $output);
  return $output;
}
?>
```

If array.py is simply:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print 1
    print 2
    print 3
    print 4
```

I will get 1,2,3,4 for my output, but I as soon as I change array.py to the following file that calls os.system, I don't get anything. So the new array.py is:

```
import os

def main():
    os.system("python test.py") #test.py creates tmp.txt with 4 lines w/ values 1,2,3,4


def output():
    f = open("tmp.txt", "r")
    myReturn = []
    currentline = f.readline()

    while currentline:
          val = currentline[:-1]  #Getting rid of '\n'
          val = int(val)
          myReturn = myReturn + [val]
          currentline = f.readline()
    f.close()
    return myReturn


if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
     o = output()
     print o[0]
     print o[1]
     print o[2]
     print o[3]
```

Also if I just run test.py, the output is the file tmp.txt:

```
 1
 2
 3
 4
```

So now, when I run my php file, the output tmp.txt is not even created in the directory and as a result I don't get any output from my php either.
I am not sure why this is happening because when I just run array.py myself, I get the desired output, and the tmp file is created.

EDIT:
I forgot to include: import os above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change exec to:

```
exec("python array.py 2>&1", $output)
```

Or check the web server or php error log.  This will return the error output from the python script to your php script (not normally what you want in production).

Comment: oh I had the import os sorry. You mean "2>&1" will return the error to my php right? So I get this broken error when running my php from loading it: Traceback (most recent call last):   File f = open(IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'tmp.txt').

Comment: Permission denied is because PHP running as one user (likely `apache`), and the folder is owned by another user (presumably you).  You will need to grant apache write access to the folder.

Comment: Well the thing is it doesn't even create that tmp.txt, so that is why it can't open it from test.py

Comment: oh just saw your comment. How would I do that? and doesn't it have permission just because the file currently doesn't exist? So If I give the apache write access to the folder, then it will be able to create tmp.txt, right?

Comment: Secondary question (you really should start marking answers as accepted - or you will stop getting quality responses).
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950470/constant-challenge-with-file-permissions

Comment: Also I am running on a server, and apache is installed on the server by root, and I don't have root access. So root would probably need to grant apache access to my folder, right?

Comment: oh yea thanks :) Sorry, not too familiar with when to do what here :) or if I should stop asking questions in comments and just find the answer to the followed questions somewhere else.